# CSS3 Scale not scaling in every direction

Tags: html, css

I am trying to attempt to have a fontawesome icon to scale in every direction so it will scale up to about 1,5 times it size. However at the moment it scales towards the top, left and right, but refuses to scale downwards, which is what I want as well. Does it have to do with the fact I use a font character instead of an image? (wouldn't make sense, since its used within an `<i></i>` element)

HTML:

```
<ul class="hoofd-menu" xmlns="">
    <li class="dekstop">
        <a id="desktop_menu" href="/desktop"><i class="fa fa-desktop text-center"></i>Desktop</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mobiel">
        <a id="mobiel_menu" href="/mobiel"><i class="fa fa-mobile text-center"></i>Mobiel</a>
    </li>
    <li class="support">
        <a id="support_menu" href="/support"><i class="fa fa-comment-o text-center"></i>Support</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS

```
nav ul.hoofd-menu {float: right;margin: 8px 0 0;padding: 0;margin-bottom: -2px;}
nav ul.hoofd-menu li {display: inline;font-size: 16px;list-style: none outside none;}
nav ul.hoofd-menu li a {color: #FFFFFF;float: left;font-size: 18px;margin-left: 40px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-right: 20px;padding-top: 20px;}
nav ul.hoofd-menu li a:hover, 
nav ul.hoofd-menu li.active a {border-bottom: 2px solid #FFFFFF;color: #FFFFFF;text-decoration: none;}
nav ul.hoofd-menu li a i {height: 40px;margin-top: -6px;transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;width: 40px; }
nav ul.hoofd-menu li a:hover i {transform: scale(1.5, 1.5); transform-origin: center, center;}
```

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mdjeqmaL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i` elements scale in all directions, you can see it [if you add some backgound](http://jsfiddle.net/mdjeqmaL/1/) to them (ironically, you had a typo in `transform-origin` notation, but that was OK because `center center` is default). What you probably need is to center the character inside the `i` element. You can [do it](http://jsfiddle.net/mdjeqmaL/3/) with following CSS:

```
line-height: 40px; /* equal to height - centers vertically */
text-align: center; /* centers horizontally */
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I feel silly i didnt recognize the icon was left alligned to the top.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{background-color: #3498db;}
nav ul.hoofd-menu {float: right;margin: 8px 0 0;padding: 0;margin-bottom: -2px;}
nav ul.hoofd-menu li {display: inline;font-size: 16px;list-style: none outside none;}
nav ul.hoofd-menu li a {color: #FFFFFF;float: left;font-size: 18px;margin-left: 40px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-right: 20px;padding-top: 20px;}
nav ul.hoofd-menu li a:hover, 
nav ul.hoofd-menu li.active a {border-bottom: 2px solid #FFFFFF;color: #FFFFFF;text-decoration: none;}
nav ul.hoofd-menu li a i {height: 40px;margin-top: -6px;transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;width: 40px; }
nav ul.hoofd-menu li a:hover i {-webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);-webkit-transform-origin: 30% 10%;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jellyfishwebdesign.nl/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<nav>                    
<ul class="hoofd-menu" xmlns="">
                        <li class="dekstop"><a id="dektop" href="/desktop"><i class="fa fa-desktop text-center"></i>Desktop</a></li>
                        <li class="mobiel"><a id="mobiel" href="/mobiel"><i class="fa fa-mobile text-center"></i>Mobiel</a></li>
                        <li class="support"><a id="support" href="/support"><i class="fa fa-comment-o text-center"></i>Support</a></li>
                    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: There are non-WebKit browsers, please don't remove standard non-prefixed properties from the code!

Comment: It does scale now in all directions, but it doensn't stay centered, and thats what i would would love to see. (in the code i put center as origin point, yet you changed it to percentages) is there anyway without using percentages? It looks decent with the screen icon, but with mobiel and support icons, it goes all weird.